# How to check this $L^p$ inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

[image]

Notation:

$I_{k,j}\subseteq (0,1)$ is an interval of length $2^{-k}$.

$\|f\|_p^p=\int_0^1 |f|^p$

$1/p+1/p'=1$

What I got is:

$\large
\begin{align*}
&2^{kp}\sum_{i=1}^{2^k}\int_{I_{k,j}}[(\int_{I_{k,j}}|f(t)|^p\,dt)2^{-kp/p'}]\,dx\\
&\leq\|f\|_p^p(2^{kp})(2^k)(2^{-k})2^{-kp/p'}\\
&=2^k\|f\|_p^p
\end{align*}
$

with an extra factor of $2^k$. Did I make any mistake?

I realised my mistake. In my context, $\bigcup_{j=1}^{2^k}I_{k,j}=(0,1)$ (I forgot to mention this). Gordon managed to solve it correctly though.

Comment: You replaced each integral on $I_{k,j}$ by an integral on $[0,1]$, roughly losing a factor $2^k$.

Comment: @Did Yes indeed. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align*}
2^{kp}\sum_{i=1}^{2^k}\int_{I_{k,j}}[(\int_{I_{k,j}}|f(t)|^p\,dt)2^{-kp/p'}]\,dx &= 2^{kp}\sum_{i=1}^{2^k} 2^{-k} 2^{-kp/p'}\int_{I_{k,j}}|f(t)|^p\,dt\\
&=2^{kp-k-kp/p'}\int_0^1|f(t)|^p\,dt\\
&=2^{kp-k-kp(1-1/p)}\int_0^1|f(t)|^p\,dt\\
&=\int_0^1|f(t)|^p\,dt.
\end{align*}

Comment: Your second equal sign should be an inequality, I guess.

Comment: I assume that $\{I_{k, j}\}_{j=1}^{2^k}$ is a disjoint partition of $(0, 1)$.

Comment: @Gordon You are indeed correct. Fantastic!